# Data undefined when getting it from a shared data between components service

Tags: angular, service, share

I have my Service which I want to use to share data between 2 of my components 
( I don't want to use queryParams or things like that because i don't want to display the data i want to share in the url bar ):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    public data: any;

    setData(param) {    
        console.log("setting data :");
        console.log(param); // param correctly display in console
        this.data = param;
    }

    getData() {
        console.log(this.data) // undefined 
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

My component A ( sender ) :
Template

```
<button (click)="navigateToB(data)">Details</button>
```

Component

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {

data;

ngOnInit() {
  ... // defining this.data
}

constructor(private router: Router, public dataService: DataService) { }

navigateToB(data) {
  this.dataService.setData(data);
  console.log(this.dataService.data); // data correctly displayed in console
  this.router.navigate(['ComponentB']);
}
```

My component B ( receiver ) : Template

```
{{ dataReceived | json }}
```

Component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-compb',
  templateUrl: './compb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./compb.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]
})

export class ComponentB implements OnInit {

  public dataReceived: any;

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataReceived = this.dataService.getData(); // undefined 
  }


}
```

app routing module :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
,
.
.
.
.,
  {
    path: 'ComponentB',
    component: ComponentB
  },
.
.
.
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is something not working?

Comment: the problem is in my title + ```// undefined```

Comment: Where is the service provided? When it is not root, then it is possible, that you have different instances of the services depending where it is provided and where the components are

Comment: Right, I forgot to add ```providers: [DataService]``` in component B, but still doesn't work (undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide the service at the component level, then each instance of the component has its own instance of the service, different from the service used by other component instances.

Provide your service in the module, or at least on a common parent component.

Since Angular 6, services are, by default, using `providedIn: 'root'` in their decorator, which automatically provides them at the root module level. That's what you should use: we're almost at Angular 9 now.